# subset of a subset of a list

Tags: r, list, sublist

In R, I have a list, composed of 12 sublists, each themselves composed of 5 subsublists as follow

[lists and sublists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Q9R.png)

In this example, I want to extract the info "MSD", for each of these sublists.

I can extract the level "statistics" for each using

```
lapply(letters, '[[', "statistics")
```

That worked well. It gave me all the values contained in the sublist "statistics", for each list
However, I want to go one level down of that, as I am not interested in the other data such as MSerror, Df, .....   Only MSD

I tried

```
lapply(letters, '[[', "statistics", "MSD")
```

and many others without success.

If I wanted only the first sublist, it will work with

```
letters[[1]][["statistics"]][["MSD"]]
```

but then, I have to do:

```
letters[[1]][["statistics"]][["MSD"]]
letters[[2]][["statistics"]][["MSD"]]
letters[[3]][["statistics"]][["MSD"]]
```

which I want to avoid for a matter of time.

thanks for your help.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I saw the posts of getting the sublist. But not on how to get one level down that, and get the "sub sub list"

Comment: You could also use a for loop if 'MSD' is always present, so you'd have `letters[[i]][["statistics"]][["MSD"]]`

Answer (score 1):

We can use a lambda/anonymous function

```
lapply(letters, function(x) x[["statistics"]][["MSD"]])
```

The benefit of this function is that if we have multiple nested elements, we don't have to call `n` `lapply` and should be faster

---

Or use `map`

```
library(tidyverse)
map(letters, ~ .x[["statistics"]][["MSD"]])
```

Also, regarding the claim that this wouldn't work if there are not some elements in the `list`,

```
set.seed(24)
lst1 <- replicate(3,  list(statistics = list(MSD = rnorm(20))))
names(lst1)[2] <- "Hello"
```

It is true that it wouldn't work.  However, it wouldn't work with the solution claimed to be work as well.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a nested lapply:

```
lapply(lapply(letters, '[[', "statistics"),`[[`,"MSD")
```

The benefit of this over @akrun's approach, which may not be relevant in this case, is that it will work even if some of the elements within the list don't have an $statistics$MSD item.