# List only values from a subset of a subset of list in R

Tags: r, list, subset, nested-lists, sublist

Hi my datastructure is attached.

[image: this]

I need to access just the `mean` under each `[[` element under `extra`.
I can do this manually individually `opt.state[["opt.path"]][["env"]][["extra"]][[1]][["mean"]]`
which gives me `NA` but there's 100 elements like this.

I followed the solution from this problem of : [subset of a subset of a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53524769/subset-of-a-subset-of-a-list)

using this `lst <- lapply(opt.state[["opt.path"]][["env"]][["extra"]], function(x) x[["mean"]])`
but end up getting two extra columns I don't need :

[image]

How do I go about getting just 1-column list with the values?

Cheers

Comment: Please follow the instructions at the top of the [tag:r] tag page when posting.  Also it is not very clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `unlist(lst)` then you will get a vector of 100 `mean` values. Columns `Name` and `Type` would appear for every list object in R when you `View` them, Or you can use `sapply()` function which would directly return a vector in this case, instead of a list.